# How to the pull the report start date less then close date?

Tags: reporting, joined-reports, report-chart

I am trying to pull the report start date < close date in opportunity object,It is possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom formula field on the opportunity object with the calculation of startdate__c - closedate.  Then you can create a report based off this field to determine which opportunities have a start date that is less than the closed date.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. If they is any chances to generate with out formula filed.

Comment: Don't think so, that's a limit of SOQL which is run as far as i know.